# Access the object for an embedded form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I would like to access the object associated with an embedded form not just the fields that I built into the form.

My use is a list of members of a group. The groups are **Group** entities, the users are **User** entities and the group members are **GroupMember** entities. **GroupMember** objects have a *permissions* field to describe the access a user has to the group.

I want a form that lists the users and has a pull-down to select the permission. Something like in my TWIG file:

```
{% for groupMember in form.members %}
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
           {{ groupMember.user.printPrettyName }}
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
           {{ form_widget(groupMember.permission) }}
       </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously the 4th line in this does not work because *groupMember* is a **FormView** object not a **GroupMember** object. When I `{{ dump(groupMember) }}` I can see see the **vars** array, with the **value** entry that contains the object being referenced (*i.e.,* the **GroupMember** object). And when I `{{ dump(groupMember.vars.value }}` it dumps this object with its properties *user*, *group*, *permission*, etc. But when I try `{{ dump(groupMember.vars.value.user.lastName) }}` I get an error **Impossible to access an attribute ("user") on a null variable.** I cannot access using `{{ dump(groupMember.user.vars) }}` because *user* is not a field in the form.

I can get something very close to what I want by adding the *user* to my form as an **EntityType** field with its *class* set to **User**, _choice_label_ set to **printPrettyName** and disabled set to **true**, then changing the 4th row above to `{{ form_widget(groupMember.user) }}`, except I don't want the grayed out / disabled pull down.

Note that this is an aesthetic thing. Putting in the the disabled pull-down field updates all the database records properly.

Comment: Could it be that `groupMember.vars.value` is `null` only for some iterations of your for loop? That would explain why you see an output when using `dump()`, but run into the error when trying to access properties of the value.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that is it. I replace the whole body of the loop with the `dump(groupMember)` and it never dumps a NULL and the User is always properly set (it is a non-null, required field in the database).

Comment: Would you be able to pus a reproducible subset of your application to GitHub or a similar platform to allow us to dig into the code?